# Push different commits in git

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

I have commited every times in the local repository and now I want to push all my commits in the remote repository. Should I do any special action or is it enough if I do a commit and push?

Example: 
I have done the Commit1 Commit2 and Commit3. Now I want to commit again (Commit4) and push all my commits (Commit1, Commit2, Commit3 and the current Commit4). With Commit and push are the last commits also pushed?

Comment: Yes. A commit always comes with its complete history.

Comment: In fact you don't push commit per commit but you push a branch. if you didn't create any then you should have a default one named "master"

Comment: I understand, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You only need to push the most recent commit, all of the previous commits will be pushed with it.

Comment: Thanks for the info!